# Laptop Dual Monitor Extended Desktop Problem

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I have an HP laptop and an external LCD. Windows 7 is configured for dual monitor extended operations.  When I first set it up the dual monitor works fine; however when I shutdown windows 7 and use my laptop in stand-alone mode the monitor remains blank.  When I plug in the external LCD the desktop display on the LCD monitor only. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> hotkey and see what that does. This should allow you to switch between displaying on either monitor, duplicating to both, or extending the screen on both.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to cycle monitor outputs between Notebook only / Both / External only? It is a keyboard kombination, often <kbd>Fn</kbd>- <kbd>F8</kbd> (at least on my Dell) ?